# "The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly." error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I have updated xamarin.forms to the lastest stable version(v3.1.0583944) and the error below is showing up!
I already did the following

Clean solution and rebuild

Downgrade to the last stable version

deleted every reference

Thank you!

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.Logger.LogException(String subcategory,
>   String errorCode, String helpKeyword, String file, Exception e)    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Execute(IList`1& thrownExceptions)
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlTask.Execute()    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() app_ativita.Android

Comment: Is it an update from 2.x to 3.x ? If so maybe you still need to install the latest .net framework sdk? See remark https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/xamarin-forms/xamarin-forms-3.0/3.0.0/#Visual_State_Manager

Comment: I recently did the same in my projects. The solution was always: Delete BIN/OJB folders, restart visual studio, clean solution and then build.

Comment: To add a final result to this case. I had to create another application, I did all of the above and, still didn't worked.